# Simple Lambda for Alexa

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to do something rather simple, or at least I thought it was going to be simple.

I want Alexa to use a Lambda I create from scratch. I want to be able to set certain actions depending on the date. I started with Dec 24 as it's rather easy. I'm trying to set the code to say if it is Dec 24 and at or later than 2100, then do this or else do that.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
// TODO implement
var dateTime = new Date();
var day = dateTime.getDate();
var mon = dateTime.getMonth();
var hour = dateTime.getHour();
var answer = "";

if(day == 24 && month == 11 && hour >= 20) {
    answer = 'working';
    console.log(answer);
} else {
    answer = 'not working';
    console.log(answer);
}

callback(answer, 'Hello from Lambda');
};
```

I'm not a Node expert and didn't want to run a million tests, but I get this error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: ff577333-cb51-11e7-8d87-6d7ffdfe6f08 Process exited before completing request"
}
```

Is my code wrong or am I missing something? Here's another version I thought about using:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
// TODO implement
var dateTime = new Date();
var day = dateTime.getDate();
var mon = dateTime.getMonth();
var hour = dateTime.getHour();
var answer = "";

if(month == 11) {
    if(day == 24) {
        if(hour >= 20) {
            answer = 'working';
    console.log(answer);
        }
    }
} else {
    answer = 'not working';
    console.log(answer);
}

callback(answer, 'Hello from Lambda');
};
```

This is my test event that I'm using:

```
{
   "key3": "11, 9, 21",
   "key2": "12,24, 22",
   "key1": "5, 5, 5"
}
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong way to test. Hoping for some guidance.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: In your `callback`, first argument is for `error` and second argument is for `response`. You're sending your response to first argument which is being interpreted as an error.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the format of your response isn't going to work for an Alexa skill. Also, as @TomG103 mentioned in his comment, the first argument of your callback should be null.

I did a video that will show you how to create a simple Alexa skill that should be easy for you to adapt for what you're trying to do.

Here is a link to the video. https://youtu.be/UlEhXDOIPvU

I hope it helps.